# How does using document.write() to load JS files work? Is it async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've used HTML5 BoilerPlate for a while now and it has the lines:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I've always assume `document.write()` loaded the script synchronously, but this proved otherwise:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
console.log(jQuery); // not defined
</script>
<script>
console.log(jQuery); // defined
</script>
```

I expected either both to be defined (synchronous) or both undefined (asynchronous). However, it seems like the entire `<script>` tag was executed before `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>` was executed. In other words, jQuery didn't even start loading yet when the first `console.log()` was called.

However, then I tried this:

```
<script>
document.write('<script>console.log("second");<\/script>');
console.log('first');
</script>
```

It produced:

```
second
first
```

So it looks like the browser continues executing the current `<script>` block when a script is loaded, but the browser does not move on to the next `<script>`.

How exactly does this work?

**Edit:**

Regarding the comment about latency: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't get why people are upvoting without confirming it first.

I just tried this:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=script.php><\/script>');
console.log(1);
</script>
<script>
console.log(3);
</script>
```

script.php:

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/x-javascript');
sleep(1);
?>
console.log(2);
```

Console:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I would imagine the first case was caused by the latency in downloading the JS file from Google API. The second example would not have had this overhead as the `console.log` would have been put straight in to the page. I haven't tested this however, and am only making an assumption.

Comment: [Scripts without async or defer attributes, as well as inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please read the edit.

Comment: @aarosil Just confirming, "parse the page" doesn't include "parse and execute Javascript"?